# how can Access array index in spacebars In meteor

Tags: arrays, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am getting dynamic content from database and I want to to view index value like..`1,2,3,4,5,6,7` and so on.

I am using `{{ @index }}` and `{{ index }}` but it is not working for me.

```
<template name="getDynamic">    
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>First Name</td>
          <td>last Name</td>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>password</td>
          <td>Gender</td>
          <td>Trems</td>
          <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {{#each  listalltests}}  {{> list }} {{/each}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

  <template name="list">
  <tr>
    <td> {{@index}} </td> // not working
    <td> {{ username }}  </td>
     <td> {{ lastname }}  </td>
    <td> {{ email }}  </td>
    <td> {{ password }}  </td>
    <td> {{ gender }}  </td>
    <td> {{ terms }}  </td>
    <td>[<a href="#" class="delete-todo">Delete</a>] </td>
    <!-- <td>[<a href="#" class="update-todo">Update</a>] </td> -->
  </tr>
</template>
```

Is there a way to access array index in spacebars In meteor?

Answer (score 1):

Your `list` template does not know about `@index` so you need to pass it to the template.

You need therefore to call it like so

`{{ > list index=@index }}`

Of course you then need to change your code in the list template to access the item data:

`<td>{{index}}</td>`

Comment: Thank you so much.